# Is there a way to create a custom HTML validation schema for Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio, validation

Is there a way to add custom HTML validation schemes to Visual Studio?

If so, is there a resource to download schemes?

http://kennethdjones.com/public/htmlvsdd.png

*Note IE6 validation is there as a painful reminder*

Comment: do you mean using doctypes other then the ones listed?

Comment: I mean having visual studio validate the mark-up when I use different doctypes. Instead of giving a ton of warnings and red lines.